# How realistic are ice plants?

Tags: biology, flora

How realistic is it that in the future someone invents plants that can live on top of the Antarctic ice sheet or are floating on ice like in the Arctic?

Comment: Look at [lichens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) or [moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moss) for inspiration. Flowering plants on an ice sheet are probably a no-go due to the lack of nutrients.

Comment: Plants need three things: Energy (usually sunlight), water and nutrients. You need some mechanism to get nutrients onto the ice sheet if you want to have plants growing on it.

Comment: @Mike Scott That would be an answer.

Comment: @Rekesoft I think it's a bit sketchy for an answer, and I don't have references to elaborate on it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be [tag:reality-check]?

Comment: In the future = later today or in a million years? Please be aware that nobody wants to do this. Currently, Antarctica is seen as the last wild landscape on earth. This is something that needs to be protected and not filled with plants. So if you want future = within the next decades - unlikely

Comment: plants on the arctic ice? You know that ice melts every year, so the plants must also be able to swim and survive in salt water??

Comment: Just a thought , but if the plants live atop the ice when they die (assuming some process for decomposition in this sub-zero environment) would they not produce soil over time? (assuming they have some means of getting nutrients without soil in the first place)  

Or is the ice sheet constantly growing in this case, burying the decomposing matter, in which case how will the plants stay above the ever growing ice sheet?

Comment: @Stephen DiMarco possibly the dead plant would be frozen so it would not decompose.

Comment: @Anixx That's my thought too. But if we are creating plants, perhaps we can create microbes capable of breaking them down as well. Actually it may make more sense to design a small ecosystem to accomplish the task. it would be a lot more robust.

Comment: On top of?  Not likely for anything much larger than the algae mentioned in an answer, because the plant's roots need liquid water to take up nutrients.  But I was intrigued, this weekend, to see aspen trees leafed out in the local mountains, despite being in 3-5 ft of snowpack.

Comment: @jamesqf plants can melt ice.

Comment: @Anixx: To some extent, yes.  Enough to deal with an ice sheet?  I really doubt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Glacier mice.**

[image: glacier mice]

https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/69701/glacier-mice-are-scampering-balls-moss

These rootless,restless plants form around a pebble, then synchronously roll about on the bare ice.  The above linked article describes the many other creatures that find refuge within.  But it is not clear what is propelling the movement of the glacier mice.

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/herds-moss-balls-mysteriously-roam-arctic-together-180975019/

> Together the team analyzed the data of the moss balls’ movement and
>   found that they roll about an inch each day. The moss balls seem to
>   insulate the ice below them, so as the glacier surface melts, each
>   ball is sitting on a small pedestal. Eventually, it tumbles off.
>
> "The whole colony of moss balls, this whole grouping, moves at about
>   the same speeds and in the same directions," Bartholomaus tells NPR.
>   "Those speeds and directions can change over the course of weeks."
>
> He explains that herd of 30 moss mice that they observed first moved
>   slowly southward before accelerating west, and then losing speed.
>   Previous research using accelerometers had shown that the balls roll,
>   and that the balls are green all over suggests that all sides get
>   sunlight at some point. The new data show that the moss balls don’t
>   move randomly—but the researchers couldn’t yet deduce what’s driving
>   them.

So no need for invention. These are plants, not algae, and they live on ice, fair and square.  They must get nutrients from the air like epiphytes.  Water is tricky too.  Very cool "critters"!

Answer (score 12):

Ice sheet as found in Arctic and in Antarctic is basically solid water with some dust particle. Not enough to sustain anything bigger than a monocellular organism (sometimes there are massive algae efflorescence like the one in this picture: [image]

resulting in colored ice on alpine glaciers, which can rely on more substantial dust deposition from closeby regions).

If you have some rocks exposed to air and light you can at least support lichens or moss, like here:

[image]

Comment: I was going to present this answer but here it is.  So add in some images of those colored snowfields, Dutch!  Algae is at its essence a monocellular organism but they can team up to make immense structures such as kelp.

Comment: @Will, pictures added

Comment: @Willk kelp is multicellular

Comment: @Anixx - I guess because it is classified with the protists I considered kelp "at its essence" unicellular.  A prejudice.  Even if you are not a plant, fungus or animal you can still be multicellular!

Answer (score 6):

The biggest problem to overcome would be water, ironically. Arctic and Antarctic plants do exist, but they have deep root systems that burrow down below the permafrost to where they can get liquid water.  One way would be roots that were dark, even black to absorb enough heat to melt the ice just enough to extract water.

Failing that, your plants would need to have some system where they could grab moisture from the air through the sublimation of the ice as opposed to the usual transpiration that an arctic plant would use.  Your plants would also likely need to be carnivorous, as nutrients would be hard to come by on the ice, even if a root system could extract anything.  I would imagine they'd need a good way to go dormant as well to allow for periods between feeding and/or periods without sunlight.

Comment: The plant could have mechanism to melt ice. Just warm it up a bit. Plants usually naturally produce some heat, so you often can see snow melted around trees.

Comment: @Anixx - but in Antarctic, where that energy would come from?

Comment: @Anixx Assuming an earth-like planet, you'd have several months of continuing sunlight followed by darkness.  A dormancy period could handle the dart times, and there would be energy during the light times.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't believe there would be any way that a plant could grow from ice, there may be some possibility for some sort of small harvester insect to live that shapes the ice around it in such a way that it is exposed to the sun (and algae can live on top), and the insect simply survives off the algae.  We could elaborate further and say the ice is shaped into dome-like forms to intensify the sun's rays heating further the water.  You can then imagine thousands of green ice balls scattered across the landscape.  It would not have a natural predator, so assuming it could survive in the harsh environment, it would thrive as well.

**Edited:**  The algae would require minerals of course, but these are common in glaciers scraped off from rocks.

Comment: So where does that algae get its sustainance?  As other answers point out, it needs sun, water, air, *and* other minerals and organic matter.

Comment: @JDługosz There are minerals in glacial water that come from rocks that have been scraped away.  Lichen can live just fine off the nutrients that come from a rock.  I don't think it's so far fetched.

Comment: That needs to be (a significant) part of your answer!  So, it would only live where such mineral is available on the surface m that needs elaborating too, as the *top* of the ice sheet is fallen snow and it's the bottom where the minerqls are scraped.  Meltwater comes along the *bottom* out to you, so it's in the spring water.  But how does that help the algae?

Comment: @JDługosz Not sure I understand that last part.  The algae just grows because it's receiving sunlight as it would naturally.  The insect would carry with it a small colony of algae on its back that it would consequently use to create its eventual food source after the eggs hatch and the newborn harvester insects find new nests.

Comment: To review:algae neede sunlight, air, water, **and other material**.  Without dirt it can’t grow.  Re your edit: the scraping is at the base of the glacier.  The top is pure water from snowfall; no minerals *there*.

Comment: @JDługosz [Not necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirt_cone).  Though assuming dirt were not on top or close to the top, consider that sunlight passes through ice with varying degrees of intensity anyway, so my guess is that a sufficiently large ice dome could serve as the lens easily sufficient to support algae.  I think you're forgetting that I'm not proving the *existence* of such a creature, merely demonstrating that such a creature is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to preface this by saying that I am by no means a botanist, however,  you said invent, not "would a plant naturally develop."  Humans are very adaptable.  If we were told there were the world's largest deposits of platinum, gold, oil, etc in the antarctic, and all that was needed was to grow plants there, the antarctic would look like a rain forest in a heartbeat.  If all that's needed is nutrients, then couldn't the inventor also invent the nutrients or a method to get them to the plants?  The ocean is full of nutrients, so maybe these plants live on the coastline.  According to a quick wikipedia search there are many mosses and lichens.  Could those be used?  If you are writing a fiction story, I don't think it's too far out there, if you can also solve the nutrient issues stated above, but I think you would also need sufficient motivation.

Answer (score 0):

Trees that remain green in temperate zones that freeze in winter, can do so because they have roots deep enough to reach unfrozen water, and they also have anti-freeze in their sap. Pine and cedar trees get their distinct smell from the turpentine that keeps their sap from freezing.

Without that anti-freeze, the sap would freeze, expand, and crack the trunk and limbs of the tree apart.